# Moving div back and forth with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem i can't see while making a div go left and right with the `.animate` of JQuery. I'm new to this web development so i ask for your kind help.

This are the files:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav-button').click(function() {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
  });
  if ($('#nav-button').data('clicked')) {
    $('#nav-menu').animate({
      left: '200'
    }, 500);
  } else {
    $('#nav-menu').animate({
      left: '0'
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #6E6E6E;
}
#container {} .nav-button {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  width: 32px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
.nav-menu {
  background-color: #424242;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 225px;
}
.logo h3,
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Sansita One;
  color: #222;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
}
.logo h1 {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.logo h3 {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.hover-rotate:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-170deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-170deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-170deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-170deg);
  transform: rotate(-170deg);
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita+One" />
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Manuel Pepe - Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav-bar" class="nav-bar">
    <div id="container">
      <img id="nav-button" class="nav-button" src="imgs/menu.png" />
      <div id="nav-menu" class="nav-menu">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="front-page">
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>Manuel Pepe</h1>
      <h3>Test</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $navButton = $('#nav-button'),
        $navMenu = $('#nav-menu'),
        transitioning = false;

    $navButton.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('clicked', !$this.data('clicked'));

        if(!transitioning) {
           transitioning = true;
           if($navButton.data('clicked')) {
             $navMenu.animate({left: '200'}, 500, function(){
                 transitioning = false;
             });
           } else {
             $navMenu.animate({left: '0'}, 500, function(){
                 transitioning = false;
             });
           }
        }
    });
});
```

If you want it to respond when you click, then the animate logic needs to be inside of the click event handler. Plus you are setting the 'clicked' data attribute to true every time so it wouldn't change. This serves as a toggle:

```
$(this).data('clicked', !$(this).data('clicked'));
```

Comment: You should only use one `!` to toggle it. `!!` changes a value to the equivalent boolean, but doesn't change its truthiness.

Comment: Thanks!! May i ask another question? If i click on the button repeated times it will keep changing its position until it reaches the number of times i clicked. how can i prevent this?